# I want to use the output of `gcloud` in a script, but the format changes. What should I do?

Tags: gcloud

I’m using the command `gcloud compute instances list` in a script, but I’m worried that the exact output format isn’t static. What should I do?

Answer (score 44):

**You should use the `--format` flag, available for most `gcloud` commands.**

For instance, if you’d like to get the exact same output as the current (as of the time of writing of this answer) format, you can run:

```
$ gcloud compute instances list --format="table(
    name,
    zone.basename(),
    machineType.basename(),
    scheduling.preemptible.yesno(yes=true, no=''),
    networkInterfaces[0].networkIP:label=INTERNAL_IP,
    networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP:label=EXTERNAL_IP,
    status
)"
```

The output of this command will *not* change between releases, even if the default output of the command does (unless the resource being formatted changes; this should be rare).<sup>1</sup>  Showing the default format for resources in commands is a work in progress.<sup>2</sup>

You can also specify a format like YAML or JSON for machine-readable output:

```
$ gcloud compute instances list --format=yaml
$ gcloud compute instances list --format=json
```

Note that this output contains much more information than is present in the default output for this command; this is the information you have to work with when constructing a custom format.

CSV is another format option. Like `table`, it requires a *projection*–a specification for how to print each row.<sup>3</sup>

```
$ gcloud compute instances list --format="csv(name,zone,status)"
name,zone,status
example-instance,us-central1-f,RUNNING
...
```

For more information on the formatting capabilities of `gcloud`, see the output of [`gcloud topic formats`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats) and [`gcloud topic projections`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/projections).

---

1. You can see all possible fields by running `gcloud compute instances list --format=flattened`.
2. For some commands, like `gcloud beta test android locales list`, you can pass the `--verbosity=info` flag and look for `INFO: Display format`.
3. This is because CSV data cannot be nested like JSON or YAML, and the data structures being printed may be nested.

Comment: Another good reference for `--format` https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--format

Comment: Truly excellent answer!  Thanks, @zachary !!